# Ending of The Child's Eye (2010)

Tags: ending, the-childs-eye

In [The Child's Eye (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1314170/), the girl throws the book she was reading out of the van's window. What is that book? Why does she do that? After doing this, they have an accident. Can anyone explain what exactly happens at the end of this film?

Comment: Seriously man.. that movie was a cry for help. Bored me out of my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I admit it's not a perfect answer, but since nobody else bothered, I'll give it a shot. The simple answer is that **the ending is ambiguous**. We don't see what Hei is pointing at or what happens after the film cuts to black, only hear a car crash. *But here's the best theory I can come up with*.

In the beginning, Rainie says that according to her mystical book, *a pregnant woman can't kill*, otherwise she and her baby will be cursed. Near the end, we find out that the hotel owner's wife was cursed and that her babies became human-dog hybrids because *she* killed the dogs. When the wife's ghost feels that Rainie is pregnant as well, she lets her go and is able to finally find peace.

But in the twist ending, Rainie, thinking she no longer needs the book and throwing it out the window, *causes the car behind them to crash*. I assume this since there's nothing in front of the *group's* vehicle before this happens, just an empty road, so there's no reason for *them* to crash:

[image]

It makes more sense that the book obscures the windshield of the vehicle *after* them (a feeling magnified by the 3d effect; we see the book flying right at us, as if we're driving behind them). And Hei, who sensed the ghosts back at the hotel, is now pointing at *Rainie* because he's sensing that the curse will live on: Rainie is pregnant and is just about to cause a death.

(And although the connection to the Pangs' *Eye* trilogy is tenuous at best, there are tiny links that might give some credence to this theory. *The Eye* ends when a character senses that an accident on the road is going to claim many lives. *The Eye 2* introduces karma and a cursed pregnancy. And *The Eye 10* introduces a mystical ghost book.)

Comment: I think this is the best explanation that could be hoped for. I'd award the bounty, but I'm not sure how...